# Video doesn't load on iPhone 5, iOS 6

Tags: ios, html, mobile-safari, platform, video-player

I have a website, it works fine on android devices and on iPhone 5 iOS 8.1.

However, on iPhone 5 iOS 6.0 and iPhone 3GS 6.1.6 the video doesn't even play, it shows a play button with a / through it when tested on Safari or Chrome.

I've done some research, and with the iOS 6.0 update comes Safari 6.0.
Knowing this I searched for the point in time when Safari started supporting the HTML5 video tag.. the first version of Safari supporting this is Safari 3.1. according to the apple website, and according to the 'caniuse.com' website, Safari Mobile supports the HTML5 video element from 4.0 onwards...

Source(s):
http://caniuse.com/#feat=video

Code:

```
<video preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" id="background">
    <source src="background/background1.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </source>
    <source src="background/background1.webm" type="video/webm"> </source>
</video>
```

Safari supports MP4 so technically it should work, and Chrome supports MP4, webm and ogg..

So with Chrome having support since Chrome 4.0 for the HTML5 Video Tag I don't believe that this is the issue, I believe this is driver related.